# Where is Harry's Extended Family?

Tags: harry-potter

So,

In Harry Potter & the Sorcerer's Stone (movie, at least) it is mentioned that the Dursleys are the only family that Harry Potter has got to take care of him, despite their abusive nature. How come Harry didn't have any grandparents from either his mother's side or his father's side? It's unlikely that all his grandparents have died of old age already. Other then the Dursleys, there is no extended family mentioned at all. It's also never mentioned whether James Potter has any siblings or not, from what I know.

Was there really no grandparents to allow him a better childhood than living with his aunt and uncle?

Comment: I've always wondered this. Thanks for asking! Looking forward to the truth finally being discovered...hopefully!

Comment: Actually looks as if someone's already asked a more-or-less identical question.

Comment: @MattGutting I suppose it is. That question there helped. Thank you!